# Where did "Free unused nodes" checkbox go?

Tags: interface, compositing-nodes

Recently run into some memory lack while I was composing and remembered about this option. Unfortunately, it is not present in Blender since 2.77 release. Was it implemented by default in modern builds or gone away forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [removed](https://developer.blender.org/rB509953a9db61dc298eae3800e381254bbc80fe06) because, according to Sergey Sharybin:

> It was basically doing nothing, for ages.

I presume he means that it wasn't having much of an effect as opposed to people not using it.

Comment: Thanks! Haha, didn't know about this, at least it was like placebo effect.